Set custom rules for server static assets (.htaccess, Brotli)
The site is built on Joomla 5.  Brotli is in use.
If I investigate the site via PageSpeed Insights, I see the that pre-compressed files has 30 days cache while I need 365 days.
Example of static assets which is set to 30 days
Other JS files are OK (365 days).
I am using the following rules to cache static files in .htaccess:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript

  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

  <FilesMatch \.(html|xhtml|xml|shtml|phtml|php|txt)$>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
  </FilesMatch>
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

  <FilesMatch \.(ico)$>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
  </FilesMatch>
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

  <FilesMatch \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp|avif|ogg|mp4|mkv|flv|swf|wmv|asf|asx|wma|wax|wmx|wm)$>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 365 days"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 365 days"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 365 days"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 365 days"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 365 days"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 2 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 2 month"

  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 2 month"

  <FilesMatch \.(eot|ttf|otf|svg|woff|woff2)$>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2  "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 6 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 2 month"

  <FilesMatch \.(css|js)$>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 365 days"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 365 days"

  <FilesMatch \.(swf|pdf|doc|rtf|xls|ppt)$>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </FilesMatch>
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf               "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/msword            "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/rtf               "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel      "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint "access plus 1 year"

Could anyone give an advice which rules should be added to  existing .htaccess rules to resolve this problem?
Thanks.

Why would anyone "need" a cache timeout of 365 days and consider 30 days not enough?

According to such logic, it could be enough even 1 day of caching.
I want to comply to Google Page Insights and Lighthouse services.

Caching helps to reduce server load. 1 day would be possible, but for really static resources something like 30 days does make more sense indeed. I understand what you mean, though.
